# A better way to write if this then this = this / number or * number

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

Im wondering if there is a better way to write these expressions in Angular 13, They dont fit most of my more senior compatriots code, And i'd like to not add messy conditionals if not needed. They seem long winded as if I could handle this with far less characers.

```
        if(this.gkhead.height > 1000){
             this.gkhead.height = this.gkhead.height / 2.5
        };
        if(this.gkhead.width > 2000){this.gkhead.width = this.gkhead.width * 1.4};
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please provide more complete code - e.g. complete function/method/class. ["_there are significant pieces of the core functionality missing, and we need you to fill in the details. Excerpts of large projects are fine, but if you have omitted too much, then reviewers are left imagining how your program works._"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/120114)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer multiplications over divisions.
What about something like this?

```
this.gkhead.height *= (this.gkhead.height > 1000) ? 0.4 : 1
```

Also take a look at [Law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Referencing through 2 objects seems fishy. Eliminating that would make code shorter and put it into correct object.

Comment: Interesting could u elaborate for me possibly on the definitions for the bit here: ```? 0.4 : 1``` 
I'm not familiar with what's happening here. Also this is Legacy code alot of it is spagetti its just a fix for a client who refuses to upgrade

Comment: Your height variable is multiplied either by `0.4` or `1` depending on the condition.

Comment: ternary operator now I understand thanks for showing me this

Comment: You are welcome!